# Find first completely visible element in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a layout in which it has parallax effect. So this are the elements in it -

1. `AppBarLayout`
2. `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside `AppBarLayout`
3. `Toolbar` inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`
4. `RecyclerView`

All this views are within `CoordinatorLayout`. Now I require to find out what is the first completely visible item of `RecyclerView`. Normally I used following logic to get it -

```
int firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

But here I am getting lots of 1 when even 0th  position is not completely visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. As I am using `AppBarLayout`, I need to check it out whether particular view is available on screen at that particular scroll or not.

I did is:

```
@Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

        View v = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(1);
        int offset = 0;
        if (v != null) {
            offset = v.getTop();
        }

        if ((verticalOffset * -1) >= offset) {
            layoutBuy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            layoutBuy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

I used `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(1);` because I wanted to work around with that particular position which is 1.

Since, vertical offset becomes minus values while scrolling I multiplied it by -1. Then just checked whether offset and top of the view which I am looking for is same or not.

Thus while using `parallax` effect in a screen and at that same time one needs to check which view is visible in `RecyclerView`, needs the logic as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

getChildAt begins at the first visible position, not at the position of the adapter.

Here is the resulting code.

```
int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
View v = layoutManager.getChildAt(0);
if (firstVisiblePosition > 0 && v != null) {
    int offsetTop = v.getTop();
    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (firstVisiblePosition - 1 >= 0 && chatAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
         layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(firstVisiblePosition - 1, offsetTop);
    }
}
```

Comment: No. I have seen this solution somewhere else. And it's not working for me. What I need to do is, I have a view sticky at bottom, and should be made `View.GONE` once same view has been completely visible from `RecyclerView` and I am not getting updates properly for scrolling.